# how to merge several css files in pixate-freestyle-android

Tags: android, pixate

My XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"...>

    <View android:id="@+id/bar" .../>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have **default.css**:

```
#bar{ background-color: red; }
#text{ color: red; }
```

And **custom.css**:

```
#text{ color: green; }
```

If I do "**PixateFreestyle.init(this);**", I can see that by applying default.css (View - red, TextView - red).

If I do "**PixateFreestyle.init(this, "custom.css");**", I can see that by applying custom.css (View - not red, default value of view, TextView - green).

How to merge default.css and custom.css? I want to get View - red, TextView - green.

In other words, I want to initialize library with two files that styles applied from both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem, I'm using the default.css, and then I'm downloading custom.css and apply it over the default.

Answer (score 0):

change in `default.css` only with the green color because if you merge two css file it will take later one only or either you can use dynamic changing of css file after few seconds but merging at a one time i think it not possible.

Comment: Thanks! I solve my problem with applying style from both files. First, from default.css then from custom.css.